# How to replace part of a regex in hive

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I've tried to do the following operation with hive regexp_replace without success :

transforming :

```
/foo1/foo2/foo3-bar1/p-115390-20.html' or '/foo1/foo2/foo3-bar1/p-115390-35.html
```

into : `/foo1/foo2/foo3-bar1/p-115390.html`

knowing that I have urls like
 `/foo1/foo2/foo3-bar1/p-115390.html` which I don't want to be transformed : 
`/foo1/foo2/foo3-bar1/p-115390.html` stays `/foo1/foo2/foo3-bar1/p-115390.html`

I tried to use without success :

```
SELECT regexp_replace('/foo1/foo2/foo3-bar1/p-115390-20.html', 'p\-\d+(\-\d+\).html', '')
```

Numbers 115390 or 115390-20 can be any number of course.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)

Comment: Hi, this is a Hadoop question, hope that helps. No MySQL or other DBMS involved. Only Hadoop. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, don't know why I missed questions tags.

Comment: No prob, this is Hadoop with a Hive layer. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer : SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('/foo1/foo2/foo3-bar1/p-115390-20.html','(p+\-+[0-9]+)\-+[0-9]+\.+html$','$1\.html')

Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 0):

Is this an ORACLE question? (You didn't tag your DBMS) You might try this

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(COLUMNNAME,'(\/foo1\/foo2\/foo3\-bar1\/p-\d+)\-\d+\.html','\1.html')
```

or

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('/foo1/foo2/foo3-bar1/p-115390-20.html','(\/foo1\/foo2\/foo3\-bar1\/p-\d+)\-\d+\.html','\1.html')
```

Finally, a shorter version of that which will possibly do just as well. It depends on how strict your matching needs to be.

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('/foo1/foo2/foo3-bar1/p-115390-20.html','(p-\d+)\-\d+\.html','\1.html')
```